# Matrix transformations 2-D

Tags: matrices

So I have a question regarding matrix transformations. 
I am trying to transform a parallelogram into the unit square.
I need to find a series of matrices which transforms each point.

For example, how do I find a, b, c and d (matrix) when (0,1) is part of the unit square and (3,10) is the original point?

[a b] [3 ] = [0]
[c d] [10]   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d02VH.png)

****also, all of those are matrices in the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply out the equations you have, getting a linear system in the matrix coefficients which you can then solve.